# Minimum energy principle for stars

Tags: energy, entropy, equilibrium, stars

In Townsend's Black Hole lecture notes, he says that at equilibrium, $E = E_{grav} + E_{kin}$ is a minimum, where $E_{grav}$ is the gravitational potential energy $-\frac{GM^2}{R}$ and $$E_{kin} = nR^3\langle E\rangle$$ is the average kinetic energy. So, $E$ is the total energy. However, the minimum energy principle holds only for **closed** systems of **constant entropy**. I do not understand how stars fall in either category.

Or, is there some other principle behind why the total energy should be minimized?